# Problem deserializing generic enum with jackson

Tags: java, jackson, jackson-databind

I have a class structure like this:

```
    public class Lame<E extends Enum<E>> {
        private Enum<E> abstractType;
        
        public Enum<E> getAbstractType() {
            return abstractType;
        }
        
        @JsonCreator
        public Lame(E type) {
            this.abstractType = type;
        }
    }
    
    public class InheritLame extends Lame<InheritLame.CounterType> {
        public enum CounterType {
            ONE,
            TWO,
            THREE;
        }
        
        public String name;
        
        @JsonCreator
        public InheritLame(CounterType type) {
            super(type);
            this.name = "NAME";
        }
        
        public String getName() {
            return this.name;
        }
    }
```

When I instantiate a new InheritLame object, passing in a concrete CounterType value:

`InheritLame il = new InheritLame(InheritLame.CounterType.ONE);`

My json output is as follows:

`{"abstractType":"ONE","name":"NAME"}`

However, when I go to recreate the InheritLame object from the JSON string, I receive this error:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Cannot deserialize value of type `InheritLame$CounterType` from String "abstractType": not one of the values accepted for Enum class: \[TWO, ONE, THREE\]
at \[Source: (String)"{"abstractType":"ONE","name":"NAME"}"; line: 1, column: 2\]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException.from(InvalidFormatException.java:67)...
```

Of course my real object model is much more complex - we probably have 50 different enum types that map to the `private Enum<T> abstractType`, so creating a hierarchy on the base class is a bit unwieldy.

I've played with all kinds of annotations, but can't seem to get it to work.  Seems pretty simple, right?  I'm fairly new to Jackson, so forgive me if the answer is obvious.  Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: This doesn't make a lot of sense. You've annotated the `InheritLame` constructor as a creator, but it only has 1 arg which doesn't correspond to the JSON. Why is `name` hardcoded? And `Lame` isn't constructed by Jackson at all.

Comment: Also, you're throwing away useful type information by declaring `abstractType` as `Enum<E>` instead of just `E`.

Comment: The class structure represents a test I was doing - really has little to do with the real classes except for the Enum<E> construct

Answer (score 0):

You need to annotate `type` in the constructor so Jackson knows how to map it:

```
@JsonCreator
public InheritLame(@JsonProperty("abstractType") CounterType type) {
```

Comment: There is really no way for Jackson to look at the field names in the JSON object and decide which one is going to provide the enum value for the constructor.

Comment: Unless you use ParameterNamesModule and rename the parameter.

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't come across that.

Comment: Thank you all, especially shmosel, for the answers.  The @JsonProperty addition did the trick, although I had to experiment a bit in how it was placed due to the complexity of the class hierarchy.